# Idiom recognition using LLVM

Tags: compilation, pattern-matching, llvm, idioms

I'm trying to figure out a tool which can automatically recognize idioms in pseudo-codes written in C language. The idioms are widely-used and common patterns that exist in many computational applications.

My guess is tools like LLVM may be able to decode and list these idioms in the source code, but while I'm investigating it I couldn't find any package in LLVM to recognize these idioms.

Does anyone aware of a package in LLVM that can do the above task for me? Or any other tools that can help me to recognize these idioms? Or any other study that reports these idioms in many different benchmarks and applications?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to define or give examples of what is an idiom. Are you referring to detection in the source language or LLVM IR?

Comment: I want to detect them at the IR level, and then be able to map them into the source level. these idioms can be the most seen patterns widely in computational intensive apps. For examples certain type of loops that exist in the source code.